# Como adicionar elementos na tupla usando uma função?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, tupla

```
def funcao():
    int(input('insira um número:'))

tupla = (funcao(), funcao(), funcao(), funcao())

print(tupla.count(9))

print(tupla)
```

---

> ```
> insira um número:9
> insira um número:9
> insira um número:9
> insira um número:9
> 0
> (None, None, None, None)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

Comment: Falta retornar a entrada: `return int(input('insira um número:'))`

Comment: https://ideone.com/RUdJUB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente não entendeu bem o funcionamento da função. No caso ele executa algo e descarta qualquer informação obtida nela. Se deseja que um valor obtido dentro da função seja entregue onde a função é chamada deve usar o comando `return`. Ele tem duas capacidades: encerra o fluxo de execução da função (é verdade que sem ele também encerra no final da definição do código da função, então ele só é obrigatório para encerrar se precisar fazer antes do final, condicionalmente, claro); e também permite resultar algo, ou seja, devolver um valor que você determinará logo em seguida, e claro que se precisa devolver um valor o `return` é obrigatório, até para especificar qual é esse valor, então só faltou o `return`.

```
def funcao():
    return int(input('insira um número:'))
tupla = (funcao(), funcao(), funcao(), funcao())
print(tupla.count(9))
print(tupla)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XWbobL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cgmqqqsh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/InputTuple.py).

Também poderia ter feito sem a função:

```
tupla = (int(input('insira um número:')), int(input('insira um número:')), int(input('insira um número:')), int(input('insira um número:')))
```

Comment: No caso se eu usasse uma função com a finalidade de processamento, o que aconteceria?

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida.

Comment: def soma(n):    sum(n)

Comment: ai eu receberia o valor da soma ?. Sem usar o return ?

Comment: Não, não pode..